# dplyr - names of levels of factor not being passed properly within mutate when using rowwise()

Tags: r, dplyr

First I am very new to R, and I'm aware that I may making an obvious mistake, I have searched for an answer, but maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing.

I am trying to apply a function to add a new column to a dataframe based on the contents of that row.  But it looks to me like the values in the row are not being handled properly in the `mutate` function when using `rowwise`. I've tried to create a toy example to demonstrate my problem.

```
library(dplyr)    
x<-c("A,"B")
y<-c(1,2)
df<-data.frame(x,y)
```

Then I have a function to create a new column called `z` which adds 1 to `y` if the value of `x` is `"A"` and adds 2 to `y` if the value of `x` is `"B"`.  Note that I have added `print(x)` to show what is going on.

```
calculatez <- function(x,y){
  print(x)
  if(x == "A"){
    return (y+1)
  } 
  else{
    return(y+2)
  } 
}
```

I then try to use `mutate`:

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(z = calculatez(x,y))
```

and I get the following, 2 has been added to both rows, rather than 1 to the first row and the `"A"` and `"B"` have been passed into the function as `1` and `2`.

```
[1] 1
[1] 2
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
Groups: 

  x y z
1 A 1 3
2 B 2 4
```

If I remove the `rowwise()` function the `"A"` and `"B"` appear to be being passed properly, but clearly I don't get the right result.

```
df %>%
  mutate(z = calculatez(x,y))

[1] A B
Levels: A B
  x y z
1 A 1 2
2 B 2 3
Warning message:
In if (x == "A") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

I can get it to work if I try to do it without writing my own function and then I don't get the error message about the length of the condition. So I don't think I understand properly what `rowwise()` is doing.

```
df %>%
  mutate(z = ifelse(x=="A",y+1,y+2))

  x y z
1 A 1 2
2 B 2 4
```

But I want to be able to use my own function, because in my real application the condition is more complicated and it will be difficult to read with lots of nested `ifelse` functions in the `mutate` function.

I can get round the problem by changing my condition to `if(x==1)` but that will make my code difficult to understand.

I don't want to waste your time, so sorry if I'm missing something obvious. Any tips on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rowwise` with `do`

```
 df %>% 
 rowwise() %>% 
 do(data.frame(., z= calculatez(.$x, .$y)))
```

gives the output

```
     x y z
  #1 A 1 2
  #2 B 2 4
```

Or you could do:

```
  df %>%
  group_by(N=row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(z=calculatez(x,y))%>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-N)
```

Using a different dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(x = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), y = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1)), .Names = c("x", 
"y"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Running the above code gives:

```
 #  x y z
 #1 A 1 2
 #2 A 2 3
 #3 B 1 3
 #4 B 2 4
 #5 B 1 3
```

If you are using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, z := calculatez(x,y), by=seq_len(nrow(df))]
df
#    x y z
# 1: A 1 2
# 2: A 2 3
# 3: B 1 3
# 4: B 2 4
# 5: B 1 3
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great.  I now understand how to get what I want.  I haven't come across `do` before, so I'll read into that.  But I guess I thought that `rowwise` did the equivalent of `group_by(N=row_number())`.  For my general understanding, any ideas why my first attempt didn't work?

Comment: @techb1234  According to the help page of ?rowwise()  `‘rowwise’ is used for the results of ‘do’ when you create list-variables.` For some reason, when you combine `mutate` with row_wise() only the `else` loop from `calculatez` got executed.

Comment: Yep, because for some reason, the value of `x` gets passed as `1` or `2` not `"A"` or `"B"`, so therefore my `if(x=="A")` condition is always false.  But thanks for pointing me at the help page, it seems like `rowwise` is only meant to work with `do`.  Good to know.

Comment: I've now tested both the `rowwise() %>% do(...` and the `group_by(N=row_number()) %>% mutate(...` solutions on my real dataset (about 54k rows).  The `mutate` solution takes a couple of seconds to run.  The `do` solution takes about 3 minutes!  I guess this is because `mutate` is calling C++ code and `do` is calling R code?

Comment: @tecb1234  That's new info for me. Thanks. You may have to look at the source code.  Have you tested `data.table` solution?  I guess it would be faster than the other methods.

Comment: No idea where to start with the source code!  The `do` solution takes ~170s, the `mutate` solution takes ~2.2s, and the `data.table` solution takes ~2.0s. As you predicted, the `data.table` solution is the fastest.

Comment: @tecb1234 Please check this link `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function`

Comment: akrun, @tecb1234, simplified the `data.table` solution. `by` understands expressions.

Comment: @akrun I'd say it's a bug in rowwise() + mutate().